# HDF5 dfs to Numpy array - cannot perform numpy operations

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py, pytables

I loaded a HDF5 file from Pandas store and dtype-ed all of them as np.float64 with the following code:

```
dtypes = np.dtype([('methane_emission', np.float64), 
                   ('no2_emission', np.float64), ('co2_emission', np.float64)])

for i in range(len(ccodes)):
    ccode = ccodes[i]
    df = store.get(ccode)
    df = df.drop(columns='year')
    dset = f1.create_dataset(ccode, data=df.astype(dtypes))
```

Then the following code is throwing me the following error.

```
f1 = h5py.File('file.h5', 'r')
a = np.array(f1['xxx']).flatten()
a.astype(np.float64).sum(axis=0)
```

Cannot cast array data from dtype([('methane_emission', '<f8'), ('no2_emission', '<f8'), ('co2_emission', '<f8')]) to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'unsafe'

Comment: Looks like a `structured` array.  See the relevant numpy docs page.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.lib.recfunctions

Comment: HDF5 compound datasets are returned as recarrays. To access each field(column), you have to provide the dataset name and the field name. Here is 1 way to do it: `arr = f1[ccode]['methane_emission'][:]` ; `arr.sum()` ; then repeat for 'no2_emission' and 'co2_emission'. (I used `ccode` b/c I wasn't sure if your `'xxx'` is actually the dataset name.) I think you can also do this: `arr = f1[ccode][:]` ; `arr['methane_emission'].sum()` ; then repeat for the other 2.